# Is it possible to save user input in variables to continuously test with intellij (pycharm)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm writing a program that takes in about 15 lines of input from std in before working with the user inputted data for a class project.

sample code here

```
def get_list():
    list = input('Here at method\n').split()
    del list[0]

    return list

def main():
     state_list: get_list()
     ....(do this about for various lists and dictionaries)
```

Further down I have some logic that I want to test. Typically, I would hard code the variables and work from there. I would like to know if there's a way to run the debugger, input the variables and have them saved temporarily while going through the logic I would like to test.

I know I can do things like highlight a certain part of code and run just that, but the variables are empty at this point.

So all in all I would like to know if theres anything specific I can do with intellij/pycharm to make this possible. If not is there any plugin or IDE that does? Also, is there any specific strategy I can employ in the future for something like this?

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open Debug > Edit configurations , it should help. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window-variables.html